# Get Web Browser tool to successfully load a page

Tags: c#

I am trying to get my web browser tool in my c# application to load a webpage which contains a video. however, my page initially threw a ton of java script errors and hardly any of the page would load.

I looked around stackoverflow and came across a post saying to enable emulation in my registry using this function

```
private static void EnsureBrowserEmulationEnabled(string exename = "EXENAME.exe", bool uninstall = false)
    {

        try
        {
            using (
                var rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
                        @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true)
            )
            {
                if (!uninstall)
                {
                    dynamic value = rk.GetValue(exename);
                    if (value == null)
                        rk.SetValue(exename, (uint)11001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully enabled");
                }
                else
                {
                    rk.DeleteValue(exename);
                    MessageBox.Show("Already Enabled");
                }

            }
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error, put something here");
        }
    }
```

this allowed me to not get any errors and i can hear audio from the video playing, but the whole webbrowser tool is white. No errors are thrown so i am completely stuck on how to progress from here to getting the display to show up.

Comment: which control, which framework? windows forms, wpf, ...?

Comment: sorry! I am using the standard toolbox so the windows forms Web broswer. I am using C# .Net and i am developing on Visual studio. The application is using windows forms / metro framework forms. Hopefully this gives more of an insight!

Comment: this control is an activex shim between microsoft internet explorer and windows forms. so if something works in full IE, it *should* behave the same way when its hosted. but it often does not. maybe there is also a problem with the video plugin. does it work in normal IE? is the html page you're showing under your control, or from internet? can you try a different video format?

Comment: I am trying to stream a video from an internet streaming website. I can’t change any of the underlying structure as i have no access to the site backend. I am getting the page URL by scraping using HTML-Agility-Pack. I will have to test if it works in IE, if it does could anyone please point me in the direction of at least getting something other than a white screen to display. Thanks

Comment: This is an example link: https://solarmoviez.ru/movie/thor-the-dark-world-1843/1242436-1/watching.html. I intended originally to grab the url of the embedded movie directly but it’s hidden behind some Blob:URL which I have no idea how to change in c# to a real public url. So I’m trying to load the full page in my web browser control.

Answer (score 0):

For people struggling with this issue, I discovered 2 fixes.

1) use CefSharp browser package for c# and enable flash player etc there, this way was very buggy for me

2) force a new tab to open in chrome by calling Process.Start(“chrome”, you url); this was much easier but not as satisfying.